# A contradiction in terms?

Tags: grammar

Is the second sentence a contradiction in terms?

I went to lunch with friends but didn't eat anything.
I had lunch with friends but didn't eat anything.

Comment: "Having lunch with friends" is an event which you can take part in without actually eating. "I ate lunch with friends but didn't eat anything" would be more contradictory.

Comment: You could just have a tea or coffee. I do this frequently (I'm watching my waistline).

Answer (score 1):

'Lunch', 'dinner' etc are as much *events* as they are meals. For example, when people say "I'm going to dinner" it implies they are going out, perhaps on a date, or with family or friends. When a work colleague says "I'm having my lunch" this can be taken to be an abbreviation of 'lunch *break*' which may include a set time that is a break from work, not just the time they spend eating.

So, while there are contexts where statements like this could imply eating, there can also be more than eating involved. In your examples, it seems someone is enjoying the *social* aspects of a lunch with friends rather than partaking of food.

Having said that - your first example is much clearer at expressing this. The second is not so much a contradiction as a little confusing.